# CSS stylesheet doesn't work entirely

Tags: html, css

I have spent some of time (about one hour, probably even more) looking for what is wrong with my code on the Internet, looking for common CSS pitfalls, etc. My guess is it's something pretty silly, but I'm new at HTML and CSS.

The CSS style doesn't seem to apply properly. What should I change? Thank you for your answers in advance and sorry if I'm not asking the question exactly the way I should (I haven't posted on www.stackoverflow.com in years (literally).

What follow is the entirety of the code I have so far:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

        </script>
        <style>
            *{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
            .button{
                width:50;
                height:50;
                font-size:25;
                margin:2;
                cursor:pointer;
            }
            .textview{
                width:217;
                margin:5;
                font-size:25px;
                padding:5;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <form name = "form">
                <input class="textview">
            </form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="C"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="<"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="/"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="X"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="7"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="8"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="9"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="-"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="4"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="5"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="6"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="+"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="1"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="2"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="3"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="="></td>
                </tr>             
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="1"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="2"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="3"></td>
                    <td><input class="button" type="button" value="+"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: width, height: 50 _what_? pixels? em? That's likely where your problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) will highlight the specific problems.

A length, in CSS, requires a unit (like `px`, `em`, `%` or `vh`), and most of yours are just numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much, Quentin. You answer solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Some properties in your stylesheet are missing the unit.

You can try the following:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.textview {
    width: 217px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

The reason why the first `margin` and `padding` properties do not require an unit is because their value is `0`, thus the unit is unnecessary, though you can still add it if you wish.

Here is a list of all existing units:

```
em, ex, %, px, cm, mm, in, pt, pc, ch, rem, vh, vw, vmin, vmax
```

You can read more about them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).